# Following a dead careers link asks me to verify my account for SE Jobs even if already done

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I followed this link: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/28723/web-developer-stack-exchange-stack-exchange (to an exipred job on the old Careers site) and got a notice to verify my account so I can access the new jobs site.

I thought I'd already done that, but clicked "Yes this is correct" just in case. I followed the same link again to see if it was a possible bug and got the same message.

I'd expect to have been taken straight through to the equivalent page on the redesigned SE jobs area/site, recognising that I'd already verified my account/identity as I think it does for job listings that are still current.

Comment: Have you blocked cookies at all?

Comment: I've not blocked cookies, but not sure which PC I verified my account at prior to today so the first time it could be because of no cookies. I do still get the verify page when clicking the link repeatedly from this PC/browser though.

Comment: Can you check the console for any JS errors?

Comment: No errors, just `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (Gone)` referring to the jobs page (presumably because the job listing is no-longer active).

Comment: FYI I do have a `jobs-account-linking-success` cookie set today (so I guess it was another PC that I originally verified on).

Comment: Interesting... The banner should never be shown in that case... Looking into it

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Would you be able to verify that it works for a newer listing?

Comment: It does work for a new listing. Found a recent job and added `careers.` to the url: careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/119120/senior-engineer-build-and-deploy-devops-ticketmaster It redirected fine and didn't show any banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just switched all the banners off permanently today so I've closed this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).